# Block google to index my website for some days (For Blank website NOT wordpress)!

Tags: html, indexing, web

I have bought a new domain. I don't want to give google a bad first impression. So I want to block indexing my website for 1 year. That's a long period.

It will be a blank website (Not using wordpress or others) so how can I do that so?

And if I want to re-index my site. How can I do that?

And Is this type of blocking can harm my website to re-index?